# 'The Imperial triangles' trigonometry question

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking

There is a very well-known family of right triangles in Mathematics called "The Imperial triangles". Let me explain you how they are defined:

We say $T_n$ is the $n$-th Imperial triangle if these two conditions are met:

- Its hypothenuse has length $\frac{1}{n}$
- Water boils at the second-to-longest side

This family has a very strange property: the shortest side is the same length on every triangle. How long exactly?

> EDIT: I expected more from you. Come on, I've seen this community solve tougher ones! Let's give you a hint. Also, please stick to flat geometry (you know, like the shape of the Earth. OK. Actually, at the time they already knew the Earth wasn't flat)
>  **Water boils at 100º, 90 of them coming from the right angle**

Comment: What does it mean to be "Water boils at the second-to-longest side"? And if the $n$ continues to grow, does it mean the shortest side will be less than $\frac{1}{n}$ and goes to $0$?

Comment: @athin there is no such thing in mathematics as an "imperial triangle" ;)

Comment: I think you're using hypotenuse incorrectly. Hypotenuse does not mean the longest side. It means the side that is opposite of a right angle which I don't think is happening here.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yep I'm aware of it, but still it's kinda impossible for normal math to solve this (unless I missed something here... XD). And in normal right triangle, hypotenuse is always the longest one, no?

Comment: it doesn't say all  $T_n$ are imperial, but if n is integer only, I wonder if there are any at all.   I guess it depends on the temperature scale?

Comment: Hey OP, rot13(qbrf guvf unir fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu gur svsgrra friraglsvir fcrpvny evtug gevnatyr?)

Comment: Is there such a triangle for every positive integer $n$?

Comment: @Acccumulation Sure, why not?

Comment: @athin Please be open-minded! Don't just stick to the boring traditional rules of Math

Comment: @David in order for us not to stick to "the boring rules", you'll have to add another tag - maybe literal, or enigmatic-puzzle

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis It's just the old rules but used in an unorthodox way

Answer (score 5):

This is

> **spherical geometry**
>
>  The interior angles can sum to more than 180°.
>  It is a right triangle, so one angle is 90°.
>  The side where water boils is opposite an angle of 100° (geddit?)
>  But I think that's a red herring.
>
>  One problem is that the smallest side has to be the same length in each triangle.
>  But it cannot be longer than half the smallest hypotenuse, which tends towards 0 in the series.
>
>  So the length of the shortest side is $\frac {1} {2 n}$

Edit following a comment from OP.

> The boiling point of water isn't a red herring after all.
>  Each spherical triangle has two known angles, 90° and 100°, the third varies with $n$.
>
>  But my spherical angle geometry skills are no greater than the smallest hypotenuse.
>  So that's as far as I can go: perhaps I am on the right track, if not the required answer.

Comment: The length is the same for all triangles, so it cannot depend on $n$

Comment: It's not a complete answer. Perhaps that should have been capital $N$ (the limit of $n$).

Comment: Rules 6 and 7 of [right angles in spherical trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry#Napier's_rules_for_right_spherical_triangles) imply that $$\tan x=\cos(100°)\tan \frac 1n$$ where $x$ is the desired length, assuming that the sphere is of constant radius 1 (i.e. assuming that the radius does not depend on $n$, and that arc length and angle coincide). Seems to be a dead end, but +1 for the idea.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier... but can you progress the idea?

Comment: How is it that you there put the great Imperial triangles on the surface of s sphere? Back in the Imperial times, everyone knew the Earth was flat!

Comment: @David in order to make the tea.

Answer (score -5):

Well, I am surprised about how bad at math all of you are! Come on, this is the Puzzling site! You can do better than this!

> Water boils at the second-to-longest side (horizonal in the picture): 90 degrees come 
>  from the right angle. We still need 10 more degrees, which of course come from the 
>  other angle formed by that side.

Now that we know the smallest angle in 10º and that the hypothenuse has length
 $\frac{1}{n}$, we can calculate the length of the opposite side (the shortest side) as

> $$\frac{\sin{(10)}}{n} = \frac{\sin{(X)}}{n} = siX = 6$$

[image]

The Empire I was refering to is of  course the Roman Empire. Comments regarding tea are just disgusting!

Comment: Hey David, some friendly advice (meant well): Probably would have been good to add more hints to the question before resorting to a self-answer (we're used to puzzles with this kind of pseudo-maths solution, just sometimes it needs to be clearer that that's what's expected). And watch out with the jokey sarcasm/insults - they're likely to get you downvotes!

Comment: @Stiv I don't see how saying "you are bad at math" for not being able to solve a problem that has almost nothing to do with math is insulting. I am just pretending the problem is a math problem, then pretending people who cannot solve it are bad at math.  Anyway my reputation on this site is the last and least of my concerns. Also, even though I posted the answer, you can still try it yourself anyway!

Comment: I don't know how you can say this has "almost nothing to do with maths" when the answer relies on subverting a mathematical relationship that only people with some knowledge of geometry will get. Instead of acknowledging that my connection with 100° was on course (and only in spherical geometry can a right triangle have another angle of 100°) all you can say is that my reference to tea is disgusting.

Comment: @WeatherVane I expected this community to be at least somewhat acceptant of humor and sarcasm, but it's just as depressing as any other. I think I'm done with this! Of course when I say "that was disgusting" I am not literally meaning that

Comment: I'm just going to leave this here.  https://xkcd.com/169/

Comment: @Rubio Isn't this site precisely about communicaing badly and havnig people figure out what you actually meant?

Comment: Not even remotely. There’s a world of difference between communicating indirectly but accurately, and communicating badly.

Comment: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/87271/bankers-with-rancor Isn't this pretty much your link changing the comic-form for a stackexchange question?